# assign pointer to constant pointer in c++

Tags: c++11, pointers

I have a constant pointer `cp` that points to `A` and a non constant pointer `p` that points to `B`. I wold say that I can assign `cp` to `p`, i.e. `p=cp` because in this way both `cp` and `p` point to `A` and I cannot do the opposite: `cp=p`, because in this way I am saying that `cp` should point to `B` but `cp` is a constant pointer so I cannot change what it is pointing to.
I tried with this simple code but the result is the opposite, can someone explain me what is the correct version please?

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(0);
auto cp = v.cbegin(); // .cbegin() is constant 
auto p = v.begin(); // .begin() is non constant
```

now if I write `cp=p` the compiler doesn't mark as error, but if I write `p=cp` the compiler marks the error.

Comment: Your assumptions are completely incorrect, you cannot implicitly remove `const` from pointers. `p=cp` would suddenly allow you to modify what `cp` refers to, which you weren't allowed to before

Comment: You should look up the difference between `cbegin()` and `begin()`. Also they don't return pointers, so you are being misled by using variable names like `cp / p`.

Comment: Also pointer assignment does not check what (runtime) objects the pointers referr to, so it doesn't matter whether `cp` refers to `A` or `B` (as long as the types are compatible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cbegin is a pointer *to something that is constant*. You can change that pointer to point to something of the same constant type.

You're confusing this with a pointer, which is constant, to something that is not.

This is hard to see here, but the difference is between

```cpp
const int* cp; // pointer to a constant value, but can point to something else
int* const pc; // pointer is constant, value can change
const int* const cpc; // pointer cannot be changed, value it points to cannot be changed
```

You can never make a "pointer that points to something that's not const" point at something that is const – because that means that you could change what is const, by derefencing the pointer!

```cpp
const int value = 5; // can never change value
const int value2 = 10; // can never change value
const int* cp = &value; // our pointer to const int points at a const int
*cp = 6; // error: the value of something const can't be changed
cp = &value2; // fine, because we're pointing at a const int

int* p const = &value; // error: trying to point a pointer to non-const to a const, which would allow us to:
*p = 7; // which should be illegal.
```

Comment: so if ```const int value = 5;```

    ```const int value2 = 10; ```

   ```const int* p = &value;```

    ```const int* const cp = &value2;```

I can write ```p=cp``` and not ```cp=p```?

Comment: you of course can't assign *anything* to `const int* const cp`, it is a constant pointer, because of the second const.